# swift4 creating users info name, age and getting data back from fire base

Tags: swift, firebase

I have created firebase all good with sign in and signup I can
store images as well but can't get images back that are stored in firebase and I want to create user profile to store name and age of user,

success with login, storing image with firebase and have created real time data base child such as image user name and age but cant use in my app, issue in creating user profile and issue with getting image back from firebase storage.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var ref : DatabaseReference?

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
// get image from firebase
   // imagesFolder.

   // let imageBack = Database.database().reference().child("images").child("user")

   // self.myImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)

 // creating dataBase
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        ref?.child("images").child("username").setValue(["name":"first", "age":28])
    }

}
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

// signUp Button pressed
@IBAction func signUpButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    Auth.auth() .createUser(withEmail: emailTextField!.text!, password: passwordTextField!.text!) {(user,error)
    in
        if user != nil
        {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)
            print("SignUp Sucessfull")
        }
        else {
            print("unSucessfull")
            // uiAlert
            let alert = UIAlertController(title:"wrong Information", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okButton)
            self.present(alert,animated: true,completion: nil)
            print("login Failed")
        }
        guard let userName = self.userName.text,!userName.isEmpty else {
            print("Email is Empty");return
        }
        guard let userAge = self.ageTextField.text,!userAge.isEmpty else {
            print("Age is required"); return
        }
}
    // upload image data to firebase
    let imagesFolder = Storage.storage().reference().child("images")
    if let image =  myImage.image {

        if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) {
        imagesFolder.child("\(NSUUID().uuidString).jpg").putData(imageData, metadata: nil,completion: { (metadata,error) in

            if let error = error {                  
                // alert notification
    }
            // putData(_:metadata:completion:)
        })                
    }
}
```

I have crazy comment please ignore that !

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself for future coders this can be a reference !
  // user info stored

```
  let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let userData = ["userName": userName,
            "userAge ": userAge] as [String? : Any]


        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("users/\(userID ?? "")").setValue(userData)



}
```

now to retrieve data create a struct and put the code in view did load

```
 func fetchCurrentUserData() {   
    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUid)

    print("userRef: \(userRef)")

    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else { return }
        let uid = snapshot.key
        let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)
        self.user = user
        print(snapshot.key)

    }
}
```